# Pandas dataframe - adding a column from a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col1':['A','B', 'B', 'A']})
   col1
0    A
1    B
2    B
3    A


    other_dict = {'A':1, 'B':0}
```

I want to append a column to df, so that it looks like this:

```
    col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     0
2    B     0
3    A     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [3]:
df['col2'] = df['col1'].map(other_dict)
df

Out[3]:
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    B     0
2    B     0
3    A     1
```

Comment: It's interesting that map doesn't require the `.get`, any idea why that is?

Comment: My understanding is that this just uses the keys to perform the lookup, same as if you pass a `Series` and similarly it will bork and generate a `KeyError` if the label/key doesn't exist, in that case doing `apply(lambda x: other_dict.get(x, other_val))` would at least not go mental if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an apply:

```
In [11]: df["col1"].apply(other_dict.get)
Out[11]:
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

then assign it to the column:

```
df["col2"] = df["col1"].apply(other_dict.get)
```

---

Another which may be more efficient (if you have larger groups) is to use a transform:

```
In [21]: g = df.groupby("col1")

In [22]: g["col1"].transform(lambda x: other_dict[x.name])
Out[22]:
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

---

It's also worth linking to the [categorical section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

Comment: But that produces a Series, not a dataframe.